# Creating a map/list from a sorted SOQL query

Tags: apex, map

This is my `list` and `map`

```
List<Account> accountList = [SELECT ID, Name, Var__c, foo__c FROM Account ORDER BY Foo__c ASC];

Map<String, String> testMap = new Map<String, String>();

for(Account a : accountList)
{
  testMap.put(a.Var__c, a.foo__c);
}
```

These are my account records

[image]

Since I am creating a list and further a map from a sorted SOQL, can I safely assume that `testMap` will always contain only one record with key, value pair as `{X,3}` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes. Each subsequent put to an already existing key will vacate the previous value, so under these circumstances, the key `x` will have the value `3` associated to it, and the map will have only one entry.

Answer (score 0):

Map can only contains unique Keys only, Value could be duplicate.

In your case when you put last value `3` into `x` key it will replace existing value.

**Example:**

```
Map<Integer, String> m1 = new Map<Integer, String>();
m1.put(1, 'Value 1');
m1.put(2, 'Value 2');
System.debug('Excepted - Value 1 Key 1 : '+m1.get(1));
System.debug('Excepted - Value 2 Key 2 : '+m1.get(2));
m1.put(1, 'Value 3');
m1.put(2, 'Value 4');
System.debug('Excepted - Value 3 Key 1 : '+m1.get(1));
System.debug('Excepted - Value 4 Key 2 : '+m1.get(2));
m1.put(1, 'Value 5');
System.debug('Excepted - Value 5 Key 1 : '+m1.get(1));
```

**Output :**

[image: Debug Log]

**Reference** : https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexref.meta/apexref/apex_methods_system_map.htm